# Hiding Columns in RDLC (selecting Header and Value Textbox individually) leaves whitespace

Tags: c#, reporting, rdlc

Report hides the column looking at the value of a parameter. And it does that alright, but when it hides it, it leaves whitespace. Here is a screenshot.

[image]

This is how the column (header textbox and value textbox individually) are hidden, after sending "True" in the value of the parameter.

[image]

Is there a way to remove the whitespaces.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are setting visibility on cells, not the column itself. If you set visibility condition on the column, the white spaces will be removed automatically.