# how to solve columns not all appearing in reportviewer/rdlc in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, linq, reporting, rdlc, reportviewer

I'm trying to solve columns not all appearing in reportviewer/rdlc in VB.NET

I have the code below, but this is still wrong.

is there any other method please guide me

Thanks

```
Public Class Form2
Dim tps As New Tableproductservice() 
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim form2 = New Form3()
        Dim rds = New ReportDataSource("DataSet1", tps.Loaddata("A"))
        form2.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
        form2.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds)
        form2.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "transposerowtocolumnsqlmsaccessvbnet.Report1.rdlc"
        form2.ShowDialog()
    End Sub
Public Class Tableproductservice
    Private connectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\transposerowtocolumnsqlmsaccessvbnet.accdb;Persist Security Info=False"

 Dim sql = <sql>
                      TRANSFORM Sum(Tableproduct.[Qty]) AS SumOfQty
SELECT Tableproduct.Codeproduct AS [CodeProduct], Tableproduct.Colour AS [Colour],Sum(Tableproduct.Qty) AS [Total]
FROM Tableproduct INNER JOIN SizeProduct ON Tableproduct.Size = SizeProduct.Size
WHERE Tableproduct.Codeproduct = ?
GROUP BY Tableproduct.Codeproduct, Tableproduct.Colour
PIVOT SizeProduct.Size;
                  </sql>.Value
        Using _conn = New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
            Return _conn.Query(Of Tableproduct)(sql, New With {Key .CodeProduct = CodeProduct}).ToList()
        End Using
    End Function
End Class
Public Class Tableproduct
    Public Property CodeProduct() As String
    Public Property Colour() As String
    Public Property S() As Integer
    Public Property M() As Integer
    Public Property L() As Integer
    Public Property XL() As Integer
    Public Property Total() As Integer
End Class
Public Class SizeProduct
    Public Property Size() As String
    Public Property Sequence() As Integer
End Class
```

below screenshot of results from code above

[image: Result in Printviewer-rdlc for codeproductA]

[image: Result in Printviewer-rdlc for codeproductB]

Desired Result :

Where For Codeproduct : A

| CodeProduct | Colour | S | M | L | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Black |  | 20 |  | 20 |
| A | White | 15 |  | 10 | 25 |

Where For Codeproduct : B

| CodeProduct | Colour | S | XL | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B | Blue | 20 |  | 20 |
| B | White |  | 15 | 15 |

Comment: Try: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35871291/14171304 / https://stackoverflow.com/q/43199806/14171304 / https://stackoverflow.com/q/26343993/14171304 / https://stackoverflow.com/q/36864100/14171304

Comment: @dr.null , 
Thank you for your advice

Answer (score 0):

As per this link the solution

Here's [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35871291/rdlc-report-hiding-columns-if-data-is-empty)!

and
Here's [a link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-us/471938e3-17eb-444e-a75e-ef05e371fbb3/how-to-hide-column-of-a-matrix-tablix-within-a-group?forum=sqlreportingservices)!

First right click on the column and select "Column Visibility"

Choose "Show or hide base on an expression"

and set an expression for each column

```
=iif(SUM(Fields!S.Value)=0,True,False)
=iif(SUM(Fields!L.Value)=0,True,False)
=iif(SUM(Fields!M.Value)=0,True,False)
=iif(SUM(Fields!XL.Value)=0,True,False)
```

[image: Result in Printviewer-rdlc for codeproductA-solution]
[image: Result in Printviewer-rdlc for codeproductB-solution]

Comment: @dr.null , Thank you for your suggestions and I have updated the screenshot solution